# How to use JS function in UDF BigQuery when checking file exists in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, user-defined-functions

I'd like to use JS function in BigQuery when checking if file exists in Google Cloud Storage.
But BigQuery kept showing error when **select UDF_FUNCTION_NAME() **

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined at
```

My JS code is like this.

BUCKET PATH is gs://MY_BUCKET_PATH/FILE_NAME
This function is checking if the file exists in the path.

```
function FileExist(){
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage=new Storage();
  return (storage.bucket('MY_BUCKET_PATH').file('FILE_NAME').exists());
}
```

And my UDF is like this.

```
  My_Function ()
  RETURNS BOOL
  LANGUAGE js 
  OPTIONS (
    library=["gs://MY_BUCKET_PATH/FILE_NAME"]
  )
  AS r"""
    return FileExist();
  """;
```

How can I make this bigquery UDF use JS in google cloud storage?

I tried put JS code in udf but it didn't work because there is npm library problem I think.
So now I'm trying to use function in library.

Comment: As far as I know, udf are sandboxed and cannot access further cloud tools such as gcs. You would need to write a cloud function which can be started from bigquery as an external udf. Please describe your goal and why you would like to check for a file in gcs. There are external tables which read in files from gcs as well.

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for suggesting. But, I can't use creating external table in udf. This is for checking data quality so I need sql query that can work in dataplex. Also, the file name that I have to check keeps changing every day. Any suggestion but external table?

Comment: Agree with samuel. JS UDF can't call external API (external from BigQuery). External UDF (also called remote function) is the key here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions

Answer (score 0):

How to list all files in google cloud storage (GCS).

Please read the [manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/object-tables) first.

Lets assume that your GCS is `gs://test1234` and in the region zone `europe-west3`.

First add a connection in BigQuery:

[image]

[image]

Set the zone and the name (here) `test123`

[image]

Create this connection and go to it in BigQuery. Find under `Service account id` the e-mail address of it and copy it.

Go to IAM, add an user with that e-mail address and give this  the right to view cloud storage.
[image]

In BigQuery run this query to generate a table showing all content of the gcs bucket:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `yourdataset.yournewtable`
WITH CONNECTION `europe-west3.test123`
OPTIONS(
  object_metadata = 'SIMPLE',
  uris = ['gs://test1234/*'],
  max_staleness = INTERVAL 4 HOUR,
  metadata_cache_mode = 'MANUAL');
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I tried this also before trying with javascript. 
The reason why I gave up this solution is that I couldn't find the way of using this in one sql query with this DDL for dataplex. Since the file name in google cloud storage keeps changed, I need to use parameter in dataplex in query.